# Is it possible to poll for a schedule?

Tags: google-forms

I want to offer a form that asks people about their availability. Below is what I did using the Multiple Choice Grid, but it doesn't allow respondents to check more than one item per row (like saying "I'm available mornings *and* evenings"). I tried reversing the rows and columns but encountered the same obstacle.

Is there another way to accomplish this type of poll using Google Forms?

[image: screen cap of form]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Instead of using the multiple-choice grid question type, use the checkbox grid question type.

For details see [Choose a question for your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7322334?hl=en)